# Bind the ngFor index to Formcontrol Id

Tags: angular, ngfor, formarray

I'm trying to bind the `ngFor` index to a input `FormControlName` when the component start or add new row.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of invForm.controls.tool.controls; let i= index" [formGroupName]="i" >
    <td>
        <mat-form-field floatLabel='never'>
            <input matInput type="number" style="text-align: right" formControlName="Id"  value="{{i+1}}" >
        </mat-form-field>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I made the entire example, please take a look the id don't get the value automatic from the input.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoice-id

After a lot of research I found a simple solution with the `trackBy: trackByFn`.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of invForm.controls.tool.controls; let i= index ;trackBy: trackByFn" [formGroupName]="i"  >
```

and

```
trackByFn(index, item) {

     item.value.Id = index+1
    return index; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial value setting is not considered a change/input and therefore will not update the value on your FormControl. If you determine the id based on the length of your array, you can pass it to your add function and remove `value="{{i+1}}"` from your html:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.invForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        tool: this.formBuilder.array([this.addEqp(1) ])
    });
}

addEqp(id: number) {
    const group =  this.formBuilder.group({
        Id: [id],
        qnt: [''],
        description: [''],
        price: [''],
        total: ['']
    });
    return group;
}

addEquip() {

    const control: FormArray = this.invForm.get(`tool`) as FormArray;
    control.push(this.addEqp(control.length + 1));
}
```

`

Comment: Thank so much for you answer. It's work, but I need a id more dynamic, if I add 3 rows and delete the second row, the next id of a new row will be 3 like the last.